# Nexus 10 does not show stacktraces anymore

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, logging, samsung-nexus-10

I have an Nexus 10 with Android 4.4.4 (Stock, no root).
Today I noticed a strange behaviour: When an App crashes, the device doesn't show the Stacktrace in Logcat. 
 
I purposely implemented a Bug in an App (parseInt("A)") without any try/catch. If I execute this on Nexus 10 the App just freezes and shows the "App isn't responding" Dialog 
In Logcat it shows only one line: `threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception`.
Does anyone know how I can get my Stacktraces back?

Comment: How are you viewing the log output? Very likely you've forgotten you have a filter set on it which is hiding the exception output.

Comment: I already checked for filters. I tried viewing it on IDE and Console on different computers.

Comment: Did you recently switched to ART? Maybe this stuff is hiding StackTraces.

Comment: Hi, no, haven't tried ART on this device yet. Also did a factory reset that didn't help.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, my real device is not showing stacktrace but avd is showing. this happened when I installed a custom ROM in the device. I haven't found any solution yet.